# How to retrieve my location and phone number from facebook in Android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am a newbie in Android.I have integrated Facebook with Android. I have retrieved the id,name and the profile picture. I want to retrieve my phone number and location from Fb. I can't understand the permissions settings and all. I have done the following coding. i want someone to explain to me step by step what to do. My codes are as follows:

**MainActivity.class**

```
session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(MainActivity.this).setCallback(statusCallback).setPermissions(permissions));
    new Request(
       session,
       "/me?fields=location",
           null,
           HttpMethod.GET,                         
           new Request.Callback() {
                 public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    // handle the result 
                    // f
                     Map<String, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                     GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                     responseMap = graphObject.asMap();
                     String location = responseMap.get("location").toString();
                     Log.i("location",""+location);
                 }
           }
        ).executeAsync();

   Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session.isOpened()) {
      Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           if(user!=null){
                final String t1=user.getId();
                final String t2=user.getName();
           }
        }
    });
```

**Error Logs:**

```
   04-15 10:19:13.024: E/AndroidRuntime(17207): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   04-15 10:19:13.024: E/AndroidRuntime(17207): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.taskmanager/com.example.taskmanager.MainActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to open an already opened session.
   04-15 10:19:13.024: E/AndroidRuntime(17207):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
   04-15 10:19:13.024: E/AndroidRuntime(17207):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
  04-15 10:19:13.024: E/AndroidRuntime(17207):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
  04-15 10:19:13.024: E/AndroidRuntime(17207):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
  04-15 10:19:13.024: E/AndroidRuntime(17207):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  04-15 10:19:13.024: E/AndroidRuntime(17207):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  04-15 10:19:13.024: E/AndroidRuntime(17207):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
  04-15 10:19:13.024: E/AndroidRuntime(17207):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  04-15 10:19:13.024: E/AndroidRuntime(17207):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 04-15 10:19:13.024: E/AndroidRuntime(17207):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
  04-15 10:19:13.024: E/AndroidRuntime(17207):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
  04-15 10:19:13.024: E/AndroidRuntime(17207):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  04-15 10:19:13.024: E/AndroidRuntime(17207): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to open an already opened session.
 04-15 10:19:13.024: E/AndroidRuntime(17207):   at com.facebook.Session.open(Unknown Source)
 04-15 10:19:13.024: E/AndroidRuntime(17207):   at com.facebook.Session.openForRead(Unknown Source)
 04-15 10:19:13.024: E/AndroidRuntime(17207):   at com.example.taskmanager.MainActivity.updateView(MainActivity.java:85)
  04-15 10:19:13.024: E/AndroidRuntime(17207):  at com.example.taskmanager.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
  04-15 10:19:13.024: E/AndroidRuntime(17207):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5203)
    04-15 10:19:13.024: E/AndroidRuntime(17207):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
   04-15 10:19:13.024: E/AndroidRuntime(17207):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
04-15 10:19:13.024: E/AndroidRuntime(17207):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fetch the phone number of the user.

To fetch the location, you need the:

- API Call: `/me?fields=location` - [Demo](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dlocation)
- Permission: `user_location`
  Check [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook#step3) how to ask for the additional permissions using android sdk.

Code to get the location:

```
new Request(
   session,
   "/me?fields=location",
   null,
   HttpMethod.GET,
   new Request.Callback() {
     public void onCompleted(Response response) {
         /* handle the result */
     }
   }
).executeAsync();
```

See what all fields are available for a user: [`/{user-id}`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user)

Comment: I have edited the code and got the errors. please guide me as I am finding it difficult to understand it.

Comment: That's something related to the facebook session handling I guess. I just gave you the concept, am not into the android.

Comment: May be you can ask this as a separate question explaining the problem properly